# ResultSet: Values are not able to insert to HashMap

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, hashmap, resultset

I have a function, which sends a query to my db and saves the result into a resultset. Another function should take the values of the resultset and put it in a hashmap. if i debug my code, the function which gets the data of db, returns values within the resultset, but if i give that resultset as an parameter to the hashmap function, it says that the resultset would be empty. I am sitting on this problem since yesterday and can't find any answer. Can somebody find any mistake in my code?

This is my Hashmap function and the one for creating the resultset.

```
public HashMap<String, List<ResultSet>> toHashMap(ResultSet rset) throws SQLException, IOException {
        HashMap<String, List<ResultSet>> hmap = new HashMap<String, List<ResultSet>>();
        while (rset.next()) {
            String Processday = rset.getString("PROCESSDAY");
            if (hmap.containsKey(Processday)) {
                List<ResultSet> s = hmap.get(Processday);
                s.add(rset);
            } else {
                List<ResultSet> newList = new ArrayList();
                newList.add(rset);
                hmap.put(Processday, newList);
            }
            System.out.println(hmap.size());
            // convertToKML(distance, ax, ay, sx, sy, out);
        }
        return hmap;
    }
```

and that's my resultset function.

```
public ResultSet getDBData(Connection conn, String[] args, RequiredMethods kml) throws SQLException{
        ResultSet rset;
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql_query;
        String[] userinput = kml.getUserInput(args);
        // String sql_query = "SELECT * from STOPPOINT_CORRECTED_BVAGG WHERE
        // trunc(PROCESSDAY) BETWEEN to_date('" + dateargs +"','ddmmyy') AND
        // to_date('" + toDate +"','ddmmyy') AND actualx is not null and
        // actualy is not null and distance is not null";


        if(userinput[0].isEmpty()){
            sql_query = "select distinct(trunc(PROCESSDAY)) PROCESSDAY,STOPPOINTID,ACTUALX,ACTUALY,SCHEDULEDX,SCHEDULEDY, DISTANCE from tabletest  WHERE trunc(PROCESSDAY) = to_date('" + kml.getDateAsString()
                + "','ddmmyy') AND actualx is not null and actualy is not null and distance is not null";
        }
        else if (userinput[1] == null) {
            sql_query = "select distinct(trunc(PROCESSDAY)) PROCESSDAY,STOPPOINTID,ACTUALX,ACTUALY,SCHEDULEDX,SCHEDULEDY, DISTANCE from tabletest  WHERE trunc(PROCESSDAY) = to_date('" + userinput[0]
                    + "','ddmmyy') AND actualx is not null and actualy is not null and distance is not null";
        }else{
            sql_query = "select distinct(trunc(PROCESSDAY)) PROCESSDAY,STOPPOINTID,ACTUALX,ACTUALY,SCHEDULEDX,SCHEDULEDY, DISTANCE from tabletest  WHERE trunc(PROCESSDAY) BETWEEN to_date('" + userinput[0]
                    + "','ddmmyy') AND to_date('" + userinput[1]
                    + "','ddmmyy') AND actualx is not null and actualy is not null and distance is not null";
        }
        System.out.println(sql_query);
        rset = stmt.executeQuery(sql_query);
        System.out.println("Query sent");



                    /*while(rset.next()){
                        System.out.println(rset.getString("ACTUALX"));  
                    }*/


        return rset;
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], at minimum include the code that calls both `getDBData` and `toHashMap`. In any case, your resource management is incorrect, so that might be involved here. The lifetime of a statement should be longer than the lifetime of a result set. The fact you create and subsequently leak a statement within `getDBData` is not good, but doesn't seem the cause. Also your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection given the concatenation of values (which, yet again, might lead to incorrect conditions, which may simply mean your query doesn't generate values).